# How to modify the proof-environment

Tags: proof-package

I wonder if it's possible to make the QED symbol in the proof environment clickable, to redirect to some given website.
Concretely, the syntax would be something like this:

```
\begin{proof}[Sketch of the Proof.][url="..."]
.
.
.
\end{proof}
```

Comment: I'm curious to have the a concrete use case for this.

Comment: In my setting, I have a proof on paper (PDF) and a proof on a website. The curious reader can see the proof in full detail by visiting the corresponding link.

Comment: Great idea! I will do the same for my lessons in high school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it with `amsthm`'s proof environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % For links, provides \href
\usepackage{amsthm}  % For proof environment
\usepackage{amssymb}  % For \square symbol
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\(\square\)}}
    Test
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

You can then create your own environment that is defined in a similar way:

```
\newenvironment{linkproof}[2][]{%
    \begin{proof}[#1]
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\href{#2}{\(\square\)}}
}{%
    \end{proof}
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\square\)}
}
```

Which is then used as

```
\begin{linkproof}[ABC]{www.google.com}
    Test
\end{linkproof}
```

You could also edit the definition of `proof` so it has this behaviour as well.

Comment: If the link contains the symbol #, the latex compiler complains with your solution. It says " Illegal parameter number in definition of \qedsymbol."

Comment: Oh, I can just put \# instead.